# Why is text not appearing in my <path> element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I want to show some text inside a custom shape I have drawn using the SVG `<path>` element. I've tried using many elements `<h1>`'s, `<p>`'s and a few others, but nothing is appearing.

Here is my React components code:

```js
export default function Segment({ pathData, keyName }) {
  return (
      <path d={pathData} stroke='red' fillOpacity={0.1} fill="green">
        <p style={{backgroundColor: 'purple'}}>I want to put some text here, like the {keyName}</p>
      </path>
  )
}
```

As I said, I've tried a bunch of different elements and I have tried changing the colors and background colors so that the element and text will stand out so I can find it easily, but I still can't see anything.

Comment: Have you tried `<text>`? You can't just put html elements inside svg

Comment: SVG is not HTML. It renders primitive grafics elements at a defined place on a canvas. If you want text - [`<text>`](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_text.asp) is also just a grafics element - to appear "inside" a shape, you have to place them both at coordinates **you have to compute** so that the visual effect is achieved. Nesting grafics elements is never allowed. There is no semantic relationship between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SVG, `<text>` is a separate object. You don’t put text **inside** other shapes, you put it **in front of them**. There is no concept of text filling a shape (box), like it does in HTML.

```css
.d1 {
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
}
.d1 svg {
  background: lime;
  width: 140px;
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
<svg viewBox="0 0 140 140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="20" y="20" width="100" height="100" style="stroke: rgb(38, 0, 255); stroke-width: 2px; fill: rgb(251, 255, 0);"/>
  <text style="white-space: pre; fill: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13.9px;" x="36.787" y="66.866">This text is</text>
  <text style="white-space: pre; fill: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13.9px;" x="27.113" y="82.798">inside the box</text>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't realise you couldn't nest elements in SVG. Thank you!